# Merging 2 tables horizontally

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables Parents and kids in a MySQL DB, I would like to merge these 2 tables

[image] [image]

[image]

I would like to know how to query both the tables so I get the following result (query), is this possible? if so, how could I do this?

Comment: That does not look like a sensible data model to begin with.

Comment: Your data is not consistent. In your table, Neils parent is Glenn(parents = 3) but in your result Neils parents are Mort and Murial(id = 4)

Comment: @anton  yea i made a mistake there, my bad, but i hope its still clear what im going for. Ill fix it soon.

Comment: @PHPhil, yew it is still clear what you are going for. Check answers...

Comment: I would suggest making a single name attribute for parent instead of father and mother. Then give each kid a motherid and a fatherid. This should give you a cleaner schema

Comment: This is a rather old-fashioned model :-(

Answer (score 0):

This should work(sort of):

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM Parents 
     JOIN kids 
     ON parents.id = kids.parent
```

That will give you a result where each Child is on its own line though parents of multiple children will be repeated. This is probably a slightly nicer way of doing it. Your way is possible but it is a pain. You can find the answer on here, it is something that is asked fairly often.

Can I also suggest changing your structure?
I would suggest making a single name attribute for parent instead of father and mother and giving each represented person their own DB entry. Then give each kid a "motherId" and a "fatherId" instead of the combined "parents" attribute. Maybe also try to get into the habit of using "attribueId" attributes to clarify your relationships. This should give you a cleaner schema and be much easier to work with. As it is you have a coupled "parents" entity which needlessly links the father and mother or forces a null value to appear. If instead you have a "parent" entity you have much more freedom. It changes your logical 1 to 1 into a 1 to many.

Answer (score 0):

Simple LEFT JOIN does the job

```
 SELECT * 
     FROM Parents 
LEFT JOIN kids 
     ON Kids.parents = parent.id
```